# I'm having trouble with properly authenticating Firebase users with errors messages in Flutter

Tags: firebase, authentication, dart, flutter

I can authenticate users just fine, however, when I purposely enter an email address that doesn't exist or a proper email address, but wrong password, there seems to be a delay in the authentication error message.

I initially tried it with a Future, async and await inside, but following a udemy tutorial and he didn't use that so I took it away, but no difference in how it ran. The one thing different I'm doing than in the tutorial is I'm also updating a cloudstore database.

```
loginUser(_email, _password) {
    formkey.currentState.save();
    if (formkey.currentState.validate()) {
      _auth
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password)
          .catchError((e) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: e.message,
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
            gravity: ToastGravity.TOP,
            timeInSecForIos: 5,
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 16.0
        );
      }).then((newUser) {
        var now = new DateTime.now();
        Firestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .document(newUser.uid)
            .collection('userInfo')
            .document('userInfo')
            .setData({
          'Last login': now,
        })
            .then((onValue) {
          print('Created it in sub collection');
        }).catchError((e) {
          print('======Error======== ' + e);
        });
        getSignedInUser();
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp()),
        );
      });


    }
  }


  getSignedInUser() async {
    mCurrentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    DocumentSnapshot result = await Firestore.instance.collection('users')
        .document(mCurrentUser.uid).collection('profile').document('profile')
        .get();
    String myResult = result['First Name'];
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "Welcome $myResult!",
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.TOP,
        timeInSecForIos: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 16.0
    );
  }
}
```

My first time I enter an invalid email, I get errors in the console stating the line where e.message is called on null. if i press login again, it gives me the proper error message. Now if I put the right email address, but wrong password (in the same running instance). it says username doesn't exist. If I click it again, it gives me proper invalid password message. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried logging the error in catch besides toast? May be toast instance is not updating first time. If the error message is same then there is issue with firebase auth sdk in flutter

Comment: yes, i logged with a print statement and get same messages, but in console

Comment: hmm maybe i'll try another version of auth

Comment: tried a couple different versions and no change in behavior

Comment: tried my own error message too (instead of e.message), same delay. Also, just noticed, if I log in with a proper username and password, it says it's incorrect. Press login again with same info and it logs in 2nd time pressed.

Comment: ah ha, got it. I was passing in _email and _password to the function, but not necessary since it's global and the forms save to that global variable. Thanks